# Implementing a LinkedList of a specific class, instead of generic type

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, linked-list

I have a simple question.

I am defining a class using linked Node defined by my own, as a nested class.

I only want to use this Node for Node of ArrayLists of String, not for a generic type.

I defined the Node for a generic type T, namely HNode< T>, but I want to add methods on this Node class that uses methods of ArrayList. For example,

```
    public void forward(int n) { //return boolean??
        HNode<T> targetNode;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            targetNode = this._next;
        }
        targetNode._datum.add(this._datum.remove(this._datum.size()-1));
    }
```

inside my Node class.

It keeps giving warning that method size() is undefined for type T, and that is why I am considering changing the class definition to Node of ArrayList of String.

(First question is this: )
Is it the right approach, or is there any better way to do it??
Or can I just ignore the warning as long as I use the

Another question is this.
I declared the variable targetNode, and assigned it inside the for loop.
However, it throws a warning that targetNode needs to be assigned.

```
    public void forward(int n) { //return boolean??
        HNode<T> targetNode = this;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            targetNode = targetNode._next;
        }
        targetNode._datum.add(this._datum.remove(this._datum.size()-1));
```

Might this be a better option?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***There is a better way to do it!***

Since you wish to use the [`.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size) method of an [`Arraylist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), I would suggest making your node (and encompassing class) a type of the [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface.

The [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface guarantees that the object will have implemented a [`.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size) method and this will remove your compilation error.

[`Arraylist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) inherits from [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) as follows:
[`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)`-->`[`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)`-->`[`Arraylist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Use [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) in place of the generic `T` through your class:

```
HNode<Collection> targetNode;
```

This will allow your class to handle all classes which implement the [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface, which is a broad group of classes. This maintains your abstraction and increases the code re-usability significantly more then committing your whole class to only the [`Arraylist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: I defined my class private class HNode<T extends Collection> {
I guess this might work??

Comment: @user25409 Define the private class like so: `HNode<Collection>`

Answer (score 0):

"I only want to use this Node for Node of ArrayLists of String, not for a generic type"

Then create your type like that, drop the  generic, use: HNode instead of `HNode<T>`

And create a field of type `Arraylist<String>`.

Comment: You mean HNode< ArrayList< String>>? This did not work, and that was why I asked this question.

Comment: Sorry was still editing my answer, now its better :), Does that fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

To be able using methods of List interface you just need to replace

```
HNode<T>
```

with

```
HNode<List>
```

The warning "targetNode needs to be assigned" appears because your for loop will not to be executed if n=0. Thats why targetNode may be not assigned. And thats why you shuld to add range check or you may get NullPointerException at this line

```
targetNode._datum.add(this._datum.remove(this._datum.size()-1));
```

---

**Edit:** Also it looks like your last line is logically incorrect. remove() method returns result of operation (boolean), not the removed object itself. You need to get this element explicitly before removing, or just change you collection to LinkedList and call removeLast() method.

Comment: Reply to 'Edit:' : I checked the Javadoc, and there is two remove methods. remove() returns boolean, remove(int index) returns the removed object.

Comment: Yep, I confused the browser tab and looked into Collection interface javadoc instead of List. Sorry for this mistake. But thats the reason why you should use List interface, not the Collection as @awashburn suggested.